# MongoDB. Remove subelement from array using parent elements for query

Tags: mongodb

Here is my collection object structure

```json
"_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
"Name": "HelloWorld",
"OtherFields": "OtherValues",
"Projects" : [ 
    {
        "Project" : {
            "key" : 111
        },
        "Category" : [ 
            {
                "No" : "123"
            }, 
            {
                "No" : "987"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Project" : {
            "key" : 222
        },
        "Category" : [ 
            {
                "No" : "123"
            }, 
            {
                "No" : "987"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to delete element with Category No「123」in Project with key 111

Closer thing that I did was

```
db.project_collection.updateOne({"_id": ObjectId("collection_obj_id")}, {"$pull": { "Projects": {"$and": [ {"Project.key": 111)}, {"Category.No": "123"} ] }} })
```

[Live example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H8oNo7oc0ZX)

This command removing whole element inside `"Projects"` object

But I want to delete only `"Projects"` → `"Category"` → `[0]` subelement which has No `123`.

When I trying to change `"Projects"` after `"$pull"` to something like `"Projects.Category"` or `"Projects.$.Category"`

```
The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query
```

error occures.

So is it possible to delete subelement without creating own backend logic?

Comment: You need to use the Array Update Operator [positional $](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html).

Comment: I already tried Projects.$, Projects.$.Category.$, Projects.Category.$, Projects.$.Category with no luck

Comment: Yes, you can try the answer below by J.F. Another example [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents) using `$pull`.

Comment: One of the answers in the marked duplicates dictates a solution in the form `db.collection.update({
  _id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}, {
  $pull: {
    "Projects.$[elem].Category": {
      "No": "123"
    }
  }
}, {
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem.Project.key": 111
    }
  ]
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing `project.key` and `category.no` you can use this query:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 1,
  "Projects.Project.key": 111
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "Projects.$.Category": {
      "No": "123"
    }
  }
})
```

With the updated JSON, the `$` operator is nedded.

This query basically point to a document with `key: 111` and `_id: 1` and using `$` do the `pull`.
So it will `pull` the 'pointed' element which match `no: "123"`.

Updated example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-AHCE-SgFWX)

I have added another document with `_id: 2` to check that only one with `_id:1` is updated.

Comment: no luck :( `WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })` I can use `{"project.key": 111}` for finding element, but even if I find it I can't change

Comment: Sorry, JSON data in my question was little bit not complete. Added keys for better understanding.
Data in your example little bit differs

Comment: Updated answer with the new JSON format. Hope it helps.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! Actually I need to update specific object_id, so can you edit your answer query like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/KoMHSFcQyUf And I will check you answer as correct

Comment: Answer updated :)